# New Session ID is creating on ASP.net callBack instead of using existing Session

Tags: asp.net, session, iis

I have a code that does a callback after payment processing. This code is working from lost 3 years and it started failing all of sudden ( Only change is windows update from last month i.e 12/2019)

When the callback happened to new tab session_Start is calling causing all the session data to lose.

This issue is happening only on Windows Server 2012 R2 which is a production server.

Thanks

Comment: This callback is POST

Comment: could you please share your sample code about the session? what is your iis session state setting? please set the iis application pool recycling time and idea time out the same as a session time.

Comment: Thank you! Adding Session CookieSameSite="None" for SessionState in web.config fixed the problem

Comment: if your issue is resolved i request you to post the helpful suggestion as an answer and mark it. it will help other people who face similar issues.